# Grails upgrade to 3.3.9, cyclic dependency with hibernateDatastore

Tags: hibernate, grails, dependency-injection

I am trying to upgrade a Grails application built on Grails 3.1.4 to Grails 3.3.8. I experienced issues with 3.3.9, therefore, I decided to use 3.3.8.

I have replaced all necessary Gradle dependency packages; however, I am getting this cyclic dependency with one of my service class.

I do not expect any cyclic dependency here because this class is not used elsewhere in the application. Also, this class is not using any other service classes from the application. Yet, it is diagnosed to have cyclic dependency.

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   methodValidationPostProcessor defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]
      ↓
   hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry
┌─────┐
|  hibernateDatastore
↑     ↓
|  commissionService
└─────┘



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Which version of GORM are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/issues/127 is likely relevant.

Comment: Also https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/946

Comment: classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.1.10  // so that would be GORM 6.1.10, I think

Comment: The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/elixirgormversion uses Grails 3.3.8 and GORM 6.1.10 and does not demonstrate the problem.  You haven't shared enough info to know for sure what combo of factors is causing the problem in your project but if you can demonstrate the problem in a shareable project, it would be easy to diagnose.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, you are correct a brand new application do not exhibit this issue but the one I am trying to upgrade is having issue. I will try to isolate the issue and possibly post more information.

Comment: "...but the one I am trying to upgrade is having issue" - Right.  There are several things that could cause the issue to happen but there is no way to guess which of them applies to your project.